# Should the 'Warhammer' tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [warhammer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer) tag has a number of questions that are asking about a very wide variety of topics. They range from Warhammer 40,000, the Warhammer game rather than a tabletop RPG, and questions about Warhammer Fantasy. We already have [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp), [wh40k](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k), [rogue-trader](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-trader), and others that cover most of the Warhammer universe.

Given this information, should we remove the [warhammer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer) tag because it is so generic?

Answer (score 7):

No, we shouldn't remove it.

It covers questions about the Warhammer systems and its settings. It is not generic—it is very, very specific (to Warhammer). Given we have only seven(!) questions tagged with it in totality, it will help the Warhammer crowd in discovering questions about the topic that are otherwise very few and far between.

It's not broken as a tag, it's working fine.

Comment: I largely agree that the tag has a place, but I am worried that it will cause some confusion on what all it refers to. I think that could probably be alleviated by a good tag excerpt, and maybe adding a [tag:warhammer-fantasy] to compliment [tag:wh40k].

Comment: @AVeryLargeBear we have that already in fact: [tag:wfrp], [tag:wfrp-1e], [tag:wfrp-2e], [tag:wfrp-3e]. But unlike WH40k there is only one product line about Warhammer Fantasy afaik. If you do however think there's questions that should have a non-wfrp Warhammer fantasy tag, you're free to add it — that's how tags get created.

Comment: We do, but none of them is a good cognate of the [tag:wh40k] tag. [tag:wh40k] is generic to the whole 40k universe, and not to a specific game, like the wfrp tags.